# Messages repeating infinitely -- Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

So this is 100% a wip and I'm super confused on how to stop the discord bot from reading the same user message over and over again.

```py
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged in as')
        print(self.user.name)
        print(self.user.id)
        print('------')
       
    async def on_message(self, message):
        global choice
        global r
        # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
        if message.author.id == self.user.id:
            return
        if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
            await message.reply('Hello!', mention_author=True)
        r=0
        basic = True
        #upgrade1 = False
        choice = '!idle'
        while(choice != '!end'):
          if message.content.startswith('!idle'):
            choice= await message.reply('!click / !bank / !upgrade / !minigame / !end')
          if message.author.id == self.user.id:
              return
          if message.content.startswith('!click' or '!c'):
              r = r + 1
              await message.reply("You have " + str(r) + " Renown")
          elif message.content.startswith ('!bank'):
              await message.reply ("You have " + str(r) + " Renown")
          #elif message.content.startswith ('!upgrade' and r >= 10):
              #await message.reply('Upgrading..')
              #r = r - 10
              #basic = False
          #elif message.content.startswith  ('!upgrade' and r < 10):
            #await message.reply ('Not Enough Renown')
          elif message.content.startswith('!minigame' or '!mg'):
            #random number choosing game
            await message.reply ("Game")
          elif message.content.startswith ('!end'):
            basic = False
          #while time.time() < future:
              #r =r + .00001



client = MyClient()
client.run
```

Comment: What message is being sent repeatedly, have you tried debugging it or tried to find the source of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue comes from the `while(choice != '!end')` loop. Once the bot enters that loop, the messages he is sending within that loop of course will be repeated because you are not changing the value of `choice` unless the message is `!idle`.

Notice in your code how if the command is for example `!click`, you are sending the following message:

```
await message.reply("You have " + str(r) + " Renown")
```

But you are not changing the value of `choice`, so in the next iteration of the `while` loop it will repeat the same, once and again.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but having a `while` loop in the on_message event does not seem a good idea for me, as this is a blocking feature. In my opinion you should replace it with an `if`.